# Storing DateTime in PostgreSQL without loosing precision

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have stumped upon an issue, that whenever I load what is presumably a `DateTime` from `Postgresql` database and compare it to initial value from C# - then the data does not match. For example, here's an original `DateTime` in C#:

> Date: {09.07.2018 00:00:00}
>
> Ticks: 636667391123714378
>
> Time: {13:18:32.3714378}

Same date, returned from `DB` (after it was saved):

> Date: {09.07.2018 00:00:00}
>
> Ticks: 636667391123714370
>
> Time: {13:18:32.3714370}

It seems like upon save - `DateTime` has lost some precision. Column type in database is a `Timestamp`. So, 2 questions:

1. What will be a proper way of storing the `DateTime` in `PostgreSQL`, so I don't loose any precision?

I was thinking about saving a number of UNIX milliseconds into an `Integer` field instead, of saving `DateTime` as a `Timestamp`, i.e.:

```
DateTime myDT = DateTime.Now;
long ms = new DateTimeOffset(myDT).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

// how I do it now
var parameterOld =
    new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("dateInserted", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp) {Value = myDT };

// how I think would be a better approach
var parameterNew =
    new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("dateInserted", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { Value = ms };
```

2. Alternatively, how do I compare 2 datetimes with a highest possible precision (C#/PostgreSql)?

My current solution, which is kind of working.. But I am loosing too much precision here:

```
public static bool IsEqualWithLossOfPrecision(this DateTime timestamp1, DateTime timestamp2)
{
    return (
        timestamp1.Year == timestamp2.Year &&
        timestamp1.Month == timestamp2.Month &&
        timestamp1.Day == timestamp2.Day &&
        timestamp1.Hour == timestamp2.Hour &&
        timestamp1.Minute == timestamp2.Minute &&
        timestamp1.Millisecond == timestamp2.Millisecond
    );
}
```

Any advises on 2 questions are welcomed.

I am using the latest available version of DB (10.4), `Npgsql` library v. 4.0.0, .net framework 4.5ish, windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's timestamps have a precision limit of microseconds.

If you need more, store the nanoseconds in a separate `bigint` attribute.